# Failed to update Android SDK package list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Everytime I try to open the Player settings, it will show only blank. And the error below will be shown in the console.

I have tried to follow this link: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1320634/unable-to-list-target-platforms-when-i-try-to-buil.html
But still didn't work.

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to update Android SDK package list.
>   /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.0b1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list
>
> stderr[
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
>       at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
>       at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
>       at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
>       at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:103)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>       ... 4 more
>   ]
>   stdout[
>
> ]
>   exit code: 1
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <4e05d4950c734693b0d63f05223d7a90>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <4e05d4950c734693b0d63f05223d7a90>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager.UpdatePackagesList () (at <4e05d4950c734693b0d63f05223d7a90>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager.HighestVersionInstalled (UnityEditor.Android.SDKManager+Component tool) (at <4e05d4950c734693b0d63f05223d7a90>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidPlatformIconProvider.GetCurrentSetAndroidSDKVersion () (at <4e05d4950c734693b0d63f05223d7a90>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidPlatformIconProvider.UpdateSDKVersion () (at <4e05d4950c734693b0d63f05223d7a90>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidPlatformIconProvider.get_targetSDKSupportsAdaptiveIcons () (at <4e05d4950c734693b0d63f05223d7a90>:0)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PlayerSettingsEditorExtension.IconSectionGUI () (at <4e05d4950c734693b0d63f05223d7a90>:0)
>   UnityEditor.PlayerSettingsEditor.IconSectionGUI (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.Modules.ISettingEditorExtension settingsExtension, System.Int32 sectionIndex) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/PlayerSettingsEditor/PlayerSettingsEditor.cs:803)
>   UnityEditor.PlayerSettingsEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/PlayerSettingsEditor/PlayerSettingsEditor.cs:573)
>   UnityEditor.AssetSettingsProvider.OnGUI (System.String searchContext) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Settings/Providers/AssetSettingsProvider.cs:94)
>   UnityEditor.SettingsWindow.DrawControls () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Settings/SettingsWindow.cs:322)
>   UnityEditor.SettingsWindow.DrawSettingsPanel () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Settings/SettingsWindow.cs:313)
>   UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event evt, UnityEngine.Matrix4x4 parentTransform, UnityEngine.Rect clippingRect, System.Boolean isComputingLayout, UnityEngine.Rect layoutSize) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:281)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Before, I can see some options so that I can try to build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having this issue as well. Nothing worked until I did this:

- Go `Unity > Preferences`, select `External Tools`, deselect everything
- Close the Editor
- Open the Editor, re-enable everything you deselected
- Hit Play to force a refresh

Then build again and it'll work

Comment: Cudos to this, it worked for me (Unity 2020.3.21f1)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite your error, but this may help someone with the same same headline error in Windows with Unity 2021.3.34f1.

Scrolling down for details it shows:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.34f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\cmdline-tools\2.1\bin\\..
```

revealing a `Program Files` directory with a space but that hasn't been quoted.

I can't quite understand how this arose for me and isn't a more widespread issue. Anyway, fixed by modifying `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.34f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\cmdline-tools\2.1\bin\sdkmanager.bat` and changing line 17 from

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=%~dp0\..
```

to

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir="%~dp0\.."
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and fixed it in a different way.

Possible fix here [Failed to update Android SDK Package List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246933/failed-to-update-android-sdk-package-list-unity-2019-2-10f1/65925820#65925820)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after importing the firebase SDK into Unity 2021.3.3f1. It turned out my system variable JAVA_HOME was not pointing to the Java used by Unity (which apparantly only caused a problem in combination with firebase).

To solve it I had to

- change Windows 10  -> Settings -> System -> Edit System variables
- Change the value of "JAVA_HOME" to my Unity Java version: "F:\Programs\Unity\2021.3.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK"
- Reboot my Computer (for the JAVA_HOME change to take effect)
- In Unity: Click on Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android -> Resolve

Not sure if the last step was necessary. I tried a lot of things (including "regenerating project files" - from Unitys settings)