# Failed to update Android SDK Package List - Unity 2019.2.10f1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When I try to export the game build for the Android platform, I started getting this error:

[image]

Within the Project Settings - Minimum API Level and Target API Level not get loaded anyhow!
While I have used all default Unity provided settings to export Android build.
Here is the image to illustrate this:

[image]

Now what to do to solve this error?

I have already read all the threads related to same problem but overall I can't able to find the solution that actually worked for me.

Answer (score 20):

1. Project Settings > Player > Target API Level: Change "Automatic" to "Android 11" (or else)
2. Play once and Stop.
3. Change target api level to Automatic.

I don't know if the problem is the same, but this is how I handle it every time.

Edit: Now I just do this; I open the Other Settings Tab in Player Settings. Error appears in console. I Play and Stop it once and the error goes away (No need to change API Levels)

Comment: I have no idea how it is possible, thank you man!! you saved me today!

Comment: I don't know how but it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I wish there was something more than an upvote

Answer (score 5):

I just got the same error on MacOS using both Unity 2019.4.18.f1/2019.2.21.f1 and after a lot of messing around I think I might have figured some of it out.

At times ( don't know why ) Unity ( or something else ) starts resetting the JAVA_HOME environment variable to string empty when you start Unity. So even if you set JAVA_HOME via console or .bashrc/.zshrc depending on MacOS version it still doesn't work.

Some posts mentioned adding "/" to the end of the external tools SDK path. I think that just forces Unity to set the path again which makes it work for a while. But for me the the error just came back the second day.

I permanently fixed it adding an editor script to the Editor folder that changes the JAVA_HOME environment variable every time Unity starts/loads.

Here's the method for MacOS, just paste it in a C# script in the editor folder.

```
[InitializeOnLoadMethod]
static void SetJavaHome()
{
    //Debug.Log(EditorApplication.applicationPath);

    Debug.Log("JAVA_HOME in editor was: " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME"));

    string newJDKPath = EditorApplication.applicationPath.Replace("Unity.app", "PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK");

    if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME") != newJDKPath)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", newJDKPath);
    }

    Debug.Log("JAVA_HOME in editor set to: " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :- Edit>Prefrences>In JDK Click copy path> then Uncheck JDK and Paste the copied path again in that and after OpenJDK add \
like this : Before : C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
After : C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.3f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\

If that doesn't works than uncheck JDK,SDK,NDK,Gradle and Stop Gradle (all five boxes) than close unity. Open Again and Check all five boxes again.

Comment: Why this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but on mac os unity may use latest version of java if you have one.

If you have installed a few versions of java, you can just remove all except java v1.8.

You can check which version of java you have by typing in terminal `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`.

You should have **2** or more versions.
If you installed them with brew, you can just use brew to uninstall extra java packages.
Also you can update `JAVA_HOME` system variable by type
`echo export "JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)" >> ~/.zshrc`.

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must update your JDK to latest and then in the OS environment variables, you should delete the previous address and replace it with new installed JDK bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in macOS even after trying all the solutions.
The problem solver for me was going to my SDK path, then cmdline-tools/xx.xx/bin and right click on "sdkmanager" and clicking open, to permit it to run.

After that, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed my problem:

The problem was caused by myself by copy-pasting a newer (and unsupported) version of `cmdline-tools` in my editor files. (`...\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\cmdline-tools`)

removing that new version fixed the issue for me.