# Unity project was working fine but when trying to build now gives "CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to update Android SDK package list"

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

There was no problem with my Unity package. But on opening and trying to build have following errors

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to update Android SDK package list.
/Users/macmini/Documents/2019.3.5f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list

tderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
]
```

Comment: Might be related to this
[possible fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246933/failed-to-update-android-sdk-package-list-unity-2019-2-10f1/65925820#65925820)

Answer (score 0):

That might mean that you are trying to build for an android version which you dont have the SDK for. Or that you actually do not have am sdk installed altogether. Or simply you have moved your sdk folder somewhere else and you just need to update it in unity