# problem when importing firebase's sdk in unity

Tags: android, windows, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem when importing firebase's sdk in unity editor 2021.1.5f1 target platform is android , the problem is with keystore password "Unable to list keys in the keystore. Please make sure the location and password of the keystore is correct." am sure the password in not wrong , i was create new project and same error but when i remove all of firebase packages everything work fine and the password work without problems , i try it again in editor 2021.3.14f1 and same the problem :( i will put the error code belw and thank u.

---

```
`Unable to list keys in the keystore. Please make sure the location and password of the keystore is correct. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -Xmx4096M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.14f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

Environment Variables:
RlsSvcPort = 22112
USERDOMAIN = BOOM
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
TMP = C:\Users\love-\AppData\Local\Temp
Sys64Compilator = 5f7953b329bq95cb59798118e2ae7333
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64
PROCESSOR_REVISION = a502
OS = Windows_NT
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \\.\pipe\crashpad_17384_GUBCNOBMVGWWFSIC
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\love-
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
TEMP = C:\Users\love-\AppData\Local\Temp
PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 8
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer
HOMEDRIVE = C:
ACSetupSvcPort = 23210
Path = C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Users\love-\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\love-\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\love-\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.1.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin;C:\Python27;
ACSvcPort = 17532
USERNAME = love-
COMPUTERNAME = BOOM
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
SystemDrive = C:
windir = C:\Windows
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default
ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN = 1
CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
APPDATA = C:\Users\love-\AppData\Roaming
OneDrive = C:\Users\love-\OneDrive
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
NVIDIAWHITELISTED = 0x01
SESSIONNAME = Console
LOGONSERVER = \\BOOM
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\love-\AppData\Local
HOMEPATH = \Users\love-
SHIM_MCCOMPAT = 0x810000001
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = BOOM
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined


stderr[
Error:Invalid command keytool-list
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)`
```

Unable to list keys in the keystore. Please make sure the location and password of the keystore is correct.

Comment: I had a similar problem after importing firebase into my Unity project. At least I also got the error JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 at some point. Here is how I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620661/failed-to-update-android-sdk-package-list/75411809#75411809