# Admob and RevenueCat Compatiablitly problem in Unity3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, revenuecat, external-dependencies

After importing the RevenuCat package along side Admob or Vice versa, android resolver in unity runs and runs for like 30 mins and crashes. Even if no crash happens and the game is built, the game gives following errors.

**Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)**

```
> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
You will no longer be able to disable R8

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseCrashlytics.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
80 actionable tasks: 28 executed, 52 up-to-date

 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput)
 #5  (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&)
 #6  (Mono JIT Code) [PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:371] UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,int,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
 #7  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
 #8 mono_get_runtime_build_info
 #9 mono_runtime_invoke
 #10 mono_runtime_invoke
 #11 scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
 #12 ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)
 #13 CallMono(char const*, char const*, char const*, ScriptingArguments const&)
 #14 DoBuildPlayer(BuildPlayerSetup const&, std::vector<EditorSceneBackup, stl_allocator<EditorSceneBackup, (MemLabelIdentifier)124, 16> >&, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, dynamic_array<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, 0ul> const&, bool, BuildReporting::BuildReport&, BuildReporting::BuiltAssetBundleInfo*, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> > const&)
```

**Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**

```
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: package androidx.annotation
warning: /home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/classes.jar(com/samsung/android/gamesdk/GameSDKManager.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
                                       @Nullable final String oldSKU,
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
                                       @Nullable final String oldSKU,
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:421: error: cannot find symbol
    @NonNull
     ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:446: error: cannot find symbol
    @NonNull
     ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:461: error: cannot find symbol
    @Nullable
     ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        public void onReceived(@NonNull CustomerInfo customerInfo) {
                                ^
  symbol: class NonNull
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
8 errors
1 warning

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.AutoValue_InstallationTokenResult found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.AutoValue_InstallationTokenResult$1 found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.AutoValue_InstallationTokenResult$Builder found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.AwaitListener found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.BuildConfig found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.CrossProcessLock found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$1 found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$2 found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
```

**CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.**

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/home/vinaytejareddy/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK/bin/java -classpath "/home/vinaytejareddy/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

Environment Variables:
XMODIFIERS = @im=ibus
GDK_BACKEND = x11
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = 8809
XDG_SESSION_TYPE = x11
INVOCATION_ID = 8a222f05b6d74f44b1ddac952825483a
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
WINDOWPATH = 2
GTK_MODULES = gail:atk-bridge
SHLVL = 0
MANAGERPID = 1916
QT_IM_MODULE = ibus
LANGUAGE = en_IN:en
LOGNAME = vinaytejareddy
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = Unity
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = this-is-deprecated
JAVA_HOME = /home/vinaytejareddy/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/OpenJDK
LANG = en_IN
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = /run/user/1000
JOURNAL_STREAM = 8:43190
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = /home/vinaytejareddy/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
USERNAME = vinaytejareddy
GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = JS ERROR;JS LOG
PWD = /home/vinaytejareddy
SESSION_MANAGER = local/vinayteja:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2210,unix/vinayteja:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2210
USER = vinaytejareddy
CHROME_DESKTOP = unityhub.desktop
SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = gnome-keyring
MANDATORY_PATH = /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
NO_AT_BRIDGE = 1
XDG_DATA_DIRS = /usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/home/vinaytejareddy/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
SHELL = /usr/bin/zsh
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = /usr/share/applications/unityhub.desktop
PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
QT_ACCESSIBILITY = 1
XAUTHORITY = /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
GPG_AGENT_INFO = /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
GDMSESSION = ubuntu
__GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK = 0
XDG_SESSION_CLASS = user
HOME = /home/vinaytejareddy
DESKTOP_SESSION = ubuntu
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = ubuntu:GNOME
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = ubuntu
DISPLAY = :1
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = ubuntu
GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = stderr
DEFAULTS_PATH = /usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = 2230
XDG_MENU_PREFIX = gnome-
BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22


stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
                          ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: package androidx.annotation
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
                          ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: package androidx.annotation
warning: /home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/libs/classes.jar(com/samsung/android/gamesdk/GameSDKManager.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
                                       @Nullable final String oldSKU,
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
                                       @Nullable final String oldSKU,
                                        ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:421: error: cannot find symbol
    @NonNull
     ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:446: error: cannot find symbol
    @NonNull
     ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:461: error: cannot find symbol
    @Nullable
     ^
  symbol:   class Nullable
  location: class PurchasesWrapper
/home/vinaytejareddy/Vinay/GameDevelopment/MyGame/MyGame2.0/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/revenuecat/purchasesunity/PurchasesWrapper.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        public void onReceived(@NonNull CustomerInfo customerInfo) {
                                ^
  symbol: class NonNull
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
8 errors
1 warning

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.AutoValue_InstallationTokenResult found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.AutoValue_InstallationTokenResult$1 found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.AutoValue_InstallationTokenResult$Builder found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-interop-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.AwaitListener found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.BuildConfig found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.CrossProcessLock found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations found in modules com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.0.1:) and com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0-runtime.jar (:com.google.firebase.firebase-installations-17.1.0:)
```

**UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 5 errors**

```
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:193 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /home/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
 #0 GetStacktrace(int)
 #1 DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&)
 #2 DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
 #3  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
 #4  (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1172] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
```

Comment: I had a similar problem after importing firebase into my Unity project. At least I also got the error `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` at some point. Here is how I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75411809/2191652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First import AdMob package ,but import only the file inside the
   folder GoogleMobileAds with the name
   “GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml”
2. update the dependencies in the file to latest version, point 3 is original file, point 4 is updated file after changing versions
3. ```
   <dependencies>
     <androidPackages>
       <androidPackage spec="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0">
         <repositories>
           <repository>https://maven.google.com/</repository>
         </repositories>
       </androidPackage>
       <androidPackage spec="androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.1">
         <repositories>
           <repository>https://maven.google.com/</repository>
         </repositories>
       </androidPackage>
       <androidPackage spec="androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1">
         <repositories>
           <repository>https://maven.google.com/</repository>
         </repositories>
       </androidPackage>
     </androidPackages>

     <iosPods>
       <iosPod name="Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK" version="~> 9.11">
         <sources>
           <source>https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs</source>
         </sources>
       </iosPod>
     </iosPods>
   </dependencies>
   ```
4. https://maven.google.com/
          
        
        
          
            https://maven.google.com/
          
        
        
          
            https://maven.google.com/
          
        
      
      
         9.11">
          
            https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
5. then reimport AdMob package ,untick the “GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml” file before importing
6. android resolver will do it’s work
7. then “Clean Build” the project
8. Successfully Built and no dependency problem with RevenueCat package.